# How to fix playOnLinux?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I am new to Ubuntu and i want to install iTunes through playOnLinux.. Every time I open playOnLinux though , i get the following error :

```
PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL libraries.
You might encounter problem with your games
```

and then this error :

```
PlayOnLinux cannot find wine (from Wine)
You should install it to use PlayOnLinux
```

My ubuntu version is 16.04.. 
What I'm supposed to do ??

Comment: "PlayOnLinux cannot find wine" So, install wine, `sudo apt install wine`

Comment: Remove all of PlayOnLinux and install the `wine` command that is a great alternative to install and run any Windows app, here is my explanation : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Don't frustrate yourself trying to get iTunes running in Wine or PlayOnLinux.

Install `virtualbox-5.1`, install a current Windows guest OS, and install iTunes in that Windows guest OS.

You'll be much happier.